# Which tag should be used for questions that will lead to speculative answers?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed that there are a lot of questions on this website that will lead to primarily opinion-based or speculative answers. However, on this website, we also allow philosophical questions. Should the questions that lead to speculative answers be tagged with [philosophy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy), should them be closed as primarily opinion-based, or should we introduce a new tag like [futurism](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurism)?

I think that most of them can be tagged with [philosophy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy). A question that should be closed as primarily opinion-based is e.g. [Is it a good idea to pay for an deep learning course?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2692/2444). An example of a question that will lead to speculative answers is [Will artificial intelligence cause mass unemployment?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12940/2444).

Furthermore, I don't believe that there is the need for the tag [futurism](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurism), given that this website should be dedicated to a scientific discipline and not junk science. However, given the existing large amount of this type of questions on the website, maybe we could have a tag for this type of questions.

Answer (score 2):

I created a soft-question tag, but people don't seem to like using it. But just because a question is "soft" doesn't mean it's invalid--many of the hard science sites have the tag, which was what inspired me to add it here.

I don't know if this is fully sufficient, but at least part of the solution.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the name of the tag. Maybe people are not used to the expression "soft question", which is a little bit vague, IMHO. Maybe we can make its description a little clearer. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/63097.